# Ignore accents on letters when reading in string

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I want to implement a search function to my program, using the stream reader, I am reading in a text document with accented letters, but I need it to ignore the accented letters and upper/lower case, I know I can convert to upper or lower but my problem is the accented letters e.g "Clémentine" = "clementine".

is there any quick way to ignore such characters?

Comment: Can you add your current code so that's easier for us to help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: See the duplicate question solutions (2 are working pretty good). Add  a `.ToLower()` to the extension method and you're good to go.

Comment: sorry guys this is what I am using currently for this method https://imgur.com/gallery/RfRJArz

Comment: Have you tried the code Adrian linked (the accepted answer and the one below, mostly)? Also, if you want someone to be able to test some other solutions (if those linked are not working for you), you should post a list of test cases, since not everyone can type those symbols. An image does not help.